# Excel: How to represent data when pivot doesnt seem to work

Tags: excel, pivot, visualization

```
       A               B          B    
   1 School ID    Parameter   Score
   2 Sch109          P1       20
   3                 P2       40       
   4                 P3       50
   5                          110  #Sum of P1, P2,P3 For Sch109
   6 Sch210          P1       10
   7                 P2       30       
   8                 P3       90
   9                          130   #Sum of P1, P2,P3 For Sch210
   10 Sch100         P1       5
   11                P2       20       
   12                P3       15
   13                         40    #Sum of P1, P2,P3 For Sch100
    
    AND SO ON
```

So basically in this excel all schools have parametersP1, P2, P3 and one row where no parameter is mentioned which is sum of all parameters (P1+P2+P3) which is also shown in comments by #. I need output such that all parameters for one school are in one line.

Expected output:

```
 A             B    C   D   E
1 School ID   P1   P2   P3  Score 
2 Sch109      20   40   50  110
3 Sch210      10   30   90  130
4 Sch100      5    20   15  40
5
```

and so on.

How to do this in excel. With Pivot also I am unable to get desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my screenshot, you can try below formula in `G2` cell.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(IFERROR("C"&MATCH($F2,$A$1:$A$12,0)&":C"&MATCH($F3,$A$1:$A$12,0)-2,"C"&MATCH($F2,$A$1:$A$12,0)&":C"&LOOKUP(2,1/($C$1:$C$12<>""),ROW($C$1:$C$12)))),COLUMN(A$1))
```

For ***Score*** use simple sum formula in `J2` cell like-

```
=SUM(G2:I2)
```

[image]